# Django - build a query with these models

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

The goal is:

Admin logs in to see a list of all registered members in his association. Admin does not want to see members who are in other associations but only in his association.

Example:

Coach (Admin) want to see all of his players in Real Madrid (association) and are not interested in seeing other soccer clubs (associations) players in his team.

I have tried for a long time and ran out of ideas, so hopefully you guys have some great ideas i can try =D

Still a newbie so appreciate your help!

admin\models.py

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
    ...
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Administrator'
```

member\models.py

```
from pl.admin.models import Administrator


class Member(models.Model):
    member_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Member'


class Association(models.Model):
    asocnumber = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Administrator)
    member_no = models.ForeignKey(Member)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Association'
```

---

views.py

```
 def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if not form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'admin/signup.html',
                          {'form': form})

        else:
            ...
            asoc_name = form.cleaned_data.get('asoc_name')
            ...
            Administrator.objects.create_user(...
                                              asoc_name=asoc_name,    
                                              ...)
            user = authenticate(...
                                asoc_name=asoc_name,
                                ...)
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request, 'admin/signup.html',
                      {'form': SignUpForm()})
```

Let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're linking these models up using CharFields, which can technically work, but you probably want to use [`ForeignKeys`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

Potentially, this means having code that looks like:

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
    ...
    asoc = models.ForeignKey(Association)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Administrator'

class Member(models.Model):
    member_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asoc = models.ForeignKey(Association)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Member'


class Association(models.Model):
    asocnumber = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    member_no = models.ForeignKey(Member)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Association'
```

You can then make the kinds of queries you want. Example: given an administrator user, get all the members of his assosiation.

```
Member.objects.filter(asoc=admin.asoc)
```

Edit

Ok, when you create the Administrator user you need to pass in an association. One way to do this is to have selecting the association be a part of the sign up process. So for example you could add a `ModelChoiceField` to your sign up form, or something like that, or have the admin be placed in a default association. But the idea is that you have an association object ready when you then create the user, and you pass it in to Administrator.create_user.

Comment: Getting error of null_value `null value in column "member_no_id" violates not-null constraint`. I get null value either if i register admin or assosiation first. Is there way of implementing those id's automagically to avoid null_value?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a member_no_id in your models right now. So maybe you had one previously, and made some changes but didn't alter the database. Possibly try fix that or recreate the database.

Comment: member_no_id comes from `member_no = models.ForeignKey(Member)`. Tried recreating the database but same thing happens

Comment: Oh, ok: when you create the Association object, are you passing a member into it? eg. association = Association(..., member_no = member)? However just thinking about it, you probably don't even need that field at all since every member stores his association and so no need for the Association to keep track of just a single member.

Comment: Nope, so that may be the problem of null_values xD 
Where should i pass the association id to the admin object? views? forms?

Comment: Whereever you care the admin object you should pass in the association.  Probably the views, but depends on your code.

Comment: i have added the code from views above..should i pass it through there and how?

Comment: `Cannot assign "'dortmund'": "Administrator.asoc_name" must be a "Association" instance.`  also edited code above by passing asoc_name..that may be wrong..added choicefield in forms..let me know if u want to see it ill send it by pastebin

Comment: This means you are passing in something that is not an Association object.

Comment: not sure how to pass in `asoc_name_id` into Administrator.create_user

Comment: Simple example to show what you need. If you removed the member field from Association, then: `a = Association(asoc_name="test")`. then `a.save()`. Then, in create_user do: `Administrator.create_user(..., asoc=a).` This should validate. The next step would for you to figure out how to get the asoc from the form.

Comment: you mean `member_no = models.ForeignKey(Member)`?..removed that from the start.. `a = Association(asoc_name="test")` `a.save()`..where should i add that? im not with you on this xD